# ResultSet is not receiving Data

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I tried to verify username and password which i received from user through html, but my result set is not receiving any data , please check my sql query and correct me , thankyou

```
 String vuname=response.getParameter("username");
   String vpswd=response.getParameter("password");
        String vsql="select * from login where username = '" + vuname + "' and password = '" + vpswd + "'";
        System.out.println("----sql-----"+vsql);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(vsql); 

        out.println("This is result set "+check);
        if(!rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println("-----Failure------");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("-----Success------");
            rd.forward(request,response);
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }

  }
```

Comment: check whether you are getting desired value from getParameter().

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should **not** concatenate input into a SQL query like that. Please [learn how to use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: Do not concatenate values into a query string. It is unsafe and leaves your code vulnerable to SQL injection. Also, **do not** store passwords in plain text. In any case, without a [mcve] we can only assume that the user/password combination you tried does not match the data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next())

> A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row

So just remove next two line from your code, 'cause you try to access non-existent data.

```
    String check = rs.getString(1);/*i tried to check if my result set has any values*/
    String check1=rs.getString(2);
```

Maybe you need to add `rs.previous()` to move ResultSet in initial position before first row.

Comment: `rs.previous()` will only work with scrollable result sets. The default is forward-only.